# vimeo eventlistener to execute jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, vimeo

So I am creating a lighting dimmer to be executed when the vimeo player plays and pauses and finishes.

Right now it does not work, as I am sure it is an issue of the Jquery...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://a.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){

var vimeoPlayer = document.querySelector('iframe');

$f(vimeoPlayer).addEvent('ready', ready);

function ready(swoosh) {

    froogaloop = $f(swoosh);

    function setupEventListeners() {
        function onPlay() {
            $('body').append('<div id="dim"></div>');
            $('#dim').fadeIn(250);
        }

        function onPause() {

           $('#dim').fadeOut(500,function() { $("#dim").remove(); });
        }

        function onFinish() {
           $('#dim').fadeOut(500,function() { $("#dim").remove(); });
        }
        onPlay();
        onPause();
        onFinish();
    }
    setupEventListeners();
}

})
</script>
```

How would I go about doing this, I am not very versed in Jquery at all

Comment: what's the error you're getting in your consol? edit: also, wrap your code with `$('document').ready(function(){});`

Comment: Well at the moment I am not getting any errors, I get a `Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL` error, but I have always gotten that error when working with iframe embeds and I usually ignore them.  Other than that I am not getting an error...I did wrap it in the document ready, thanks almost forgot about that, but didnt solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

I should have posted my embed code as that was where the issue was, I had api=1 at the end of the code versus the beginning, and that was simply the answer